# PS4 plus free games

Tags: ps4

Hello guys I got a question if an example I have downloaded the free game plus of august can I play them at anytime if my subscription is on like in 3 month would they be available

Answer (score 2):

You can play the PS Plus games only while you have PS Plus Subscription.

While you don't have subscription you can't access the games.

If you have 1 month subscription, you can play the game during that month. After that you can't play it. If you then get a new subscription you can again play the game.

Comment: Note that any game you paid money for will still be playable after your subscription ends, even if you got it for super cheap due to a PS+ discount.